# Text property of radio buttons inside a groupbox to a decimal variable?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, radio-button, decimal

I've been having trouble trying to find a way to take the text property of a checked radio button and save in a decimal variable.

Currently there are three group boxes all of which have 3 radio buttons.

I need to take the text property from the checked radio buttons in each box, and save two of them as a decimal, and one of them as Int16.

decimal variablename = text property of currently selected radio button within a groupbox
int16 variable name = text property of currently selected radio button within a groupbox

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
    // define a global variable
    decimal result = 0;

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        result = decimal.Parse(radioButton1.Text);
    }

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        result = decimal.Parse(radioButton2.Text);
    }

    private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        result = decimal.Parse(radioButton3.Text);
    }
```

Make sure your radioButton text are `number` but not any `character`

Comment: I have three radio buttons inside of the groupbox, this is only for one of them, correct?

Comment: I need to store the currently selected radio button's text as a single decimal variable, not as separate ones.

decimal variablename = text property of currently selected radio button within a groupbox

Comment: use a `global variable` to store the selected result from the radioButton and use `checkedChanged` event. Check the edited solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using separate handlers can get rather clunky and hard to maintain if you want to add or remove radiobuttons.  One handler for all of them and a simple foreach to assign the handler to each radiobutton will make the code more streamlined.  Also you should always check if the radiobutton is checked, since un-checking also fires the event:

In the form's load event handler add this:

```
foreach(GroupBox gb in this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>())
}
    foreach(RadioButton rb in gb.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
    {
        rb.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);
    }
}
```

Global variable:

```
decimal result1 = 0;
decimal result2 = 0;
Int16 result3 = 0;
```

CheckedChanged handler:

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton currentrb = (RadioButton)sender;
    if(currentrb.Checked)
    {
        switch(currentrb.Parent.Name)
        {
            case "GroupBox1":
                result1 = decimal.Parse(currentrb.Text);
                break;
            case "GroupBox2":
                result2 = decimal.Parse(currentrb.Text);
                break;
            case "GroupBox3":
                result3 = Int16.Parse(currentrb.Text);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

With this the only thing that'll need attention is if you add or remove a GroupBox